# how do i pass multiple parameter to action method from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

i'm doing something like this in category.cshtml view page

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
            <option value="/product/categoryByPage/id=@Model.CategoryID,limit=15" selected="selected">15</option>
            <option value="/product/categoryByPage/id=@Model.CategoryID,limit=30"
selected="selected">30</option>
            <option value="/product/categoryByPage/id=@Model.CategoryID,limit=50"
selected="selected">50</option>
    </select>
```

and from controller :

```
[ActionName("categoryByPage")]
 public ViewResult Category(Guid id, string limit)
 {
       Category cat = db.Categories.Find(id);
       return View(cat);
 }
```

but it isn't working and controller method unable to fetch that parameters ...

thanks in advance,

Milan

Comment: Write like this:
<option value="/product/categoryByPage?id=@Model.CategoryID&limit=15" selected="selected">15</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your url as follows to work with default routing:

```
<option value="/product/categoryByPage/@Model.CategoryID?limit=50"
selected="selected">
```

Note that id is actually in the default route as the last argument, any extra parameters you need need to be provided in query string format